# iPhone FaceBook status with photo

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

I want to know is there anyway to update my FaceBook status with photo and location?

Till now I've only seen way of giving a URL to my photo. Is there any way where I just put my `UIImage` to FaceBook and send it to me/feed using `fbrequest`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try fbrequest graphpath me/photos for this.

```
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/photos"
                     andParams: params
                 andHttpMethod: @"POST"
                   andDelegate:self];
```

You can pass Image as part of the parameters. 
For location, you can add placeID for the place you want to add.
[Here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#photos) is the reference doc for Places.

Comment: where to get this place id? I want to put my own place as string. Not the id

Comment: can I put latitude and longitude?

Comment: No, you cannot add a random place with a lat, long pair. It has to be a valid place in Facebook. After all, that place needs to point to some page. That's why the place needs to be a placeID. What you can do is to get nearby places to checkin and the JSONResponse will contain place ID's which you can use here to add the location. I cannot think of any other way possible.

Comment: and how to get this nearby places?